# How to change executable icon in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-11, icons, shortcuts

How to change executable icon in Windows? not the shortcut icon but the executable itself.
I have google chrome applications that I want to change the icons of them.

Answer (score 2):

In traditional windows executables, the icons are included in a part of the .exe file called a "resource" and you use a "resource editor" to edit the resource.  (You could also modify the actual executable to point to a different resource, but that is much more difficult).

["Resource Hacker"](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) Is one such resource editor.

If you want to use the editor to replace an icon, you also need the new icon. You can use an icon editor to create or modify an icon. One such editor is [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/)

Some modern applications cannot be modified, because they are protected by their installers or by Windows. The modified executable may refuse to run, or may be automatically restored.